# TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method

Tags: python, arrays

I am having an error like this as shown below

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/tej/Desktop/Allfiles/TSAlgorithm/Rots/slidingwindow.py", line 41, in <module>

    segments = segment.slidingwindowsegment(data, fit.regression, fit.sumsquared_error, max_error)

  File "/Users/tej/Desktop/Allfiles/TSAlgorithm/Rots/segment.py", line 29, in slidingwindowsegment

    result_segment = create_segment(sequence,(seq_range[0],seq_range[1]))

  File "/Users/tej/Desktop/Allfiles/TSAlgorithm/Rots/fit.py", line 15, in regression

    p, error = leastsquareslinefit(sequence,seq_range)

  File "/Users/tej/Desktop/Allfiles/TSAlgorithm/Rots/wrappers.py", line 10, in leastsquareslinefit

    y = array(sequence[seq_range[0]:seq_range[1]+1])

TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

**Code**

```
from numpy import arange, array, ones
from numpy.linalg import lstsq

def leastsquareslinefit(sequence,seq_range):

    """Return the parameters and error for a least squares line fit of one segment of a sequence"""

    x = arange(seq_range[0],seq_range[1]+1)
    y = array(sequence[seq_range[0]:seq_range[1]+1])
    A = ones((len(x),2),float)
    A[:,0] = x
    (p,residuals,rank,s) = lstsq(A,y)
    try:
        error = residuals[0]
    except IndexError:
        error = 0.0
    return (p,error)
```

Error line is

```
y = array(sequence[seq_range[0]:seq_range[1]+1])

sequence = [2.07879, 1.10188, 0.568894, 0.394302, 0.794052, 0.428718, 0.47567, 0.452418, 0.426734, 0.768852, 0.870319, 1.30586, 0.380166, 0.569896, 0.756903, 0.586858, 0.641127, 0.692155, 1.03697, 1.03722, 1.56939, 0.281659, 0.312457, 1.33759, 1.70201, 1.35018, 1.87431, 1.65084, 1.1157, 0.562875, 0.544611, 0.556123, 0.973077, 0.535477, 0.644177, 0.784439, 0.668507, 0.58048, 0.761036, 1.27403, 0.502488, 0.383824, 0.635096, 0.553752, 0.620955, 0.727158, 0.579525, 0.912165]

seq_range = (0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, 17.0, 17.5, 18.0, 18.5, 19.0, 19.5, 20.0, 20.5, 21.0, 21.5, 22.0, 22.5, 23.0)
```

The program where i read the sequence and seq_range

```
def slidingwindowsegment(sequence, create_segment, compute_error, max_error, seq_range=None):

    if not seq_range:

        f=0.1
        a=0
        b=len(sequence)-1
        seq_range=[x * f for x in range(a, b)]
        seq_range=tuple(seq_range)

        #seq_range = (0,len(sequence)-1)
        #print (type(seq_range))

    start = seq_range[0]
    end = start
    result_segment = create_segment(sequence,(seq_range[0],seq_range[1]))
    while end < seq_range[1]:
        end += 1
        test_segment = create_segment(sequence,(start,end))
        error = compute_error(sequence,test_segment)
        if error <= max_error:
            result_segment = test_segment
        else:
            break

    if end == seq_range[1]:
        return [result_segment]
    else:
        return [result_segment] + slidingwindowsegment(sequence, create_segment, compute_error, max_error, (end-1,seq_range[1]))
```

Comment: Try `print(type(seq_range[0]))` and then re-read the error message: `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an index method`. What do you expect to get from `sequence[0.0:1.5]`?

Comment: what are `sequence` and `seq_range`?

Comment: The problem you have is caused by the indexes, these must be integers since they indicate the position of an element of the list or tuple, in your case you want to pass indexes of type 1.5 or similar.

Comment: Exactly, the indices can not be integers since they indicate the position of the iterable elements.

Comment: For example assume that `sequence = [2.07879, 1.10188, 0.568894, 0.394302]` and `seq_range = (0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5)`; And you place the `sequence[seq_range [0]: seq_range [1] +1]` this equals `sequence[0.0: 0.5]`, which means that you require indices from 0.0 to 0.5, but only indexes 0, 1, 2, 3 exist.

Comment: [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47]
[0 1]
[0 1]
[0 1 2]
[0 1 2], I understand that i will get something like this but my only worry is, Is it possible to make the gap longer? not just length 1 ??

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code is saying that you're accessing the elements of `sequence` from the index `0.0`to `0.5+1 = 1.5`. This is clearly not possibile, since `0.0` and `1.5`are not an integer values

Comment: when i have my seq_range as length= 1 i get it right but i am trying to do some graph plotting with this to find overlapping segments but with length one i was not able to find any. So i wanted to increase the gap as 0.1 to 0.10 thats why i have given like that but i understand that its not accepting float values. Is there any other way i can do it ? as i am new to python its hard.

Comment: Please see the updated question. See, My timeseries is like this before [(0, 2.0787900000000001, 1, 1.1018799999999995), (1, 1.1018800000000002, 2, 0.56889400000000001), (2, 0.56889400000000045, 3, 0.39430200000000026), (3, 0.3943020000000006, 4, 0.79405200000000042), (4, 0.79405199999999887, 5, 0.42871799999999904) . You can see the length in x axis is always 1 and i want to increase the length as 10 that is (0.1, 0.2 to 0.10 ). So these are the above steps i made and i ended up with this error. Thanks